# Make button slide out of screen

Tags: java, android, button, android-animation

I am trying to create a welcome screen for a project. The activity is called Activity_WelcomeScreen. There is a button called playButton near the centre of the screen. I want the button to slide down to bottom of the screen when the user clicks on it while the intent changes the activity to Main Activity. The fade in and fade out are working but the playButton's animation doesn't work.

- To confirm that I didn't make a mistake in the animation res file, I copied the fade out animation code from its file and put it in the slide_out_to_bottom file, and commented out the intent part. But still nothing happened.
- I've tried using getBaseContext() instead of getApplicationContext() but that didn't work either.

This leads me to think I'm passing the context wrong, but if thats not the case, please correct me.

So if anybody knows how to make this work, please put it down below. Any help is appreciated.

This is the animation resource file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="100%p"
        android:duration="1500"
        />
</set>
```

This is the onClickListener for the playButton:

```
playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                slideOutToBottom = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_out_to_bottom);

                playButton.setAnimation(slideOutToBottom);

                intentWelcomeToMain = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentWelcomeToMain);

                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing setAnimation() by startAnimation() ?

Comment: you can use animation callbacks, when the animation in compeleted, in the animation completed callback run your code for Intent. @ArnavMangla

Comment: @Nomankhanbhai I'm sorry I'm not sure I understand what you mean (I'm new to Adnroid Dev) Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Thank you so much @etienne. Just wanted to ask why startAnimation() works but setAnimation() doesn't? And primarily why setAnimation() doesn't in this case?